# Don't display repeated data output on serial monitor of arduino

Tags: arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno, rfid

In this code i am taking the TID data(20bytes of 160bits) in the form of array according to the sparkfun(manufacture) documentation and RFID tag detection code and its working correctly and getting the output of RFID tags.

Now I just need your guidance that how can i stop displaying RFID tag ID which is already displayed on serial monitor of arduino. What should i have to do!

**Arduino code:**

```
/*Reading multiple RFID tags, simultaneously!
TIDs are 20 bytes, 160 bits*/

#include <SoftwareSerial.h> //Used for transmitting
SoftwareSerial softSerial(2, 3); //RX, TX

#include "SparkFun_UHF_RFID_Reader.h" //Library for controlling the M6E Nano module
RFID nano; //Create instance

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Initializing...");

  if (setupNano(38400) == false) //Configure nano to run at 38400bps
  {
    Serial.println("Module failed to respond. Please check wiring.");
    while (1); //Freeze!
  }

  nano.setRegion(REGION_NORTHAMERICA); //Set to North America

  nano.setReadPower(1000); //10.00 dBm. 

  nano.enableDebugging(); //Turns on commands sent to and heard from RFID module
}

void loop()
{
  /*Serial.println(F("Get one tag near the reader. Press a key to read unique tag ID."));
  while (!Serial.available()); //Wait for user to send a character*/
  Serial.read(); //Throw away the user's character

  byte response;
  byte myTID[20]; //TIDs are 20 bytes
  byte tidLength = sizeof(myTID);

  //Read unique ID of tag
  response = nano.readTID(myTID, tidLength);
  if (response == RESPONSE_SUCCESS)
  {
    Serial.println("TID read!");
    Serial.print("TID: [");
    for(byte x = 0 ; x < tidLength ; x++)
    {
      if(myTID[x] < 0x10) Serial.print("0");
      Serial.print(myTID[x], HEX);
      Serial.print(" ");
    }
    Serial.println("]");
  }
  else
    Serial.println("Failed read");

}

//Gracefully handles a reader that is already configured and already reading continuously
//Because Stream does not have a .begin() we have to do this outside the library
boolean setupNano(long baudRate)
{
  nano.begin(softSerial); //Tell the library to communicate over software serial port

  softSerial.begin(baudRate); //For this test, assume module is already at our desired baud rate
  while(!softSerial); //Wait for port to open
  while(softSerial.available()) softSerial.read();
  nano.getVersion();
  if (nano.msg[0] == ERROR_WRONG_OPCODE_RESPONSE)
  {
    //This happens if the baud rate is correct but the module is doing a ccontinuous read
    nano.stopReading();

    Serial.println(F("Module continuously reading. Asking it to stop..."));

    delay(1500);
  }
  else
  {
    //The module did not respond so assume it's just been powered on and communicating at 115200bps
    softSerial.begin(115200); //Start software serial at 115200

    nano.setBaud(baudRate); //Tell the module to go to the chosen baud rate. Ignore the response msg

    softSerial.begin(baudRate); //Start the software serial port, this time at user's chosen baud rate
  }

  //Test the connection
  nano.getVersion();
  if (nano.msg[0] != ALL_GOOD) return (false); //Something is not right

  //The M6E has these settings no matter what
  nano.setTagProtocol(); //Set protocol to GEN2

  nano.setAntennaPort(); //Set TX/RX antenna ports to 1

  return (true); //We are ready to rock
}
```

Comment: I think that the users on [Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) might be better able to help you; maybe you could ask there instead. I hope you come right!

Comment: @Jǝssǝ Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what you should do in your application program.

The basic specifications of the RFID reader and RFID tag are to notify all tags within the reading range when reading is requested.

Please incorporate the following procedures / functions into the application.

1. The tag data notified from the RFID reader is stored for each reading.
2. By the next reading, the tag data notified this time is compared with previously notified data.
3. Tag data that has already been received is not displayed.

Please decide the interval and the number of times to keep record of tag data and compare it according to your specifications and requirements.

In the case of tags conforming to ISO/IEC 18000-63, duplication notification can not be made within a certain period by specifying a parameter called S flag at the time of reading request.
However, since the detailed behavior depends on the specifications of individual tags and the operating environment, use of the S flag is not recommended.